# Copy resources from child projects into fat jar root path

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

How can i collect resources from all child projects and copy them into the spring boot fat jar root path. So lets say I have 3 projects

```
|
|-> child-project-A
| -> -> -> src/main/resource/abc.txt
|-> child-project-B
|-> -> -> src/main/resource/def.txt
|-> child-project-C
|-> -> -> src/main/resource/AAA.txt
```

child-project-C depends on both A and B. Boot repackage is disabled for projects A and B and is enabled for project C so when I compile the final jar. It includes AAA.txt in the root path of the jar because its from child-project-C classpath but abc.txt and def.txt go into the jars of project-A and project-B. I would like to copy the resources from projects A and B into the root path of the final jar generated for project-C.

I have created a sample github project at https://github.com/adeelmahmood/copy-resources-fatjar-example. To try it out

1. clone the project
2. ./gradlew clean build

generated jar file under ui project has the ui.properties class in the root path of jar and shared.properties is inside the shared jar. I would like to copy the shared.properies from shared project to fat jar root path.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: added sample project

Comment: does my answer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that adding the following piece of code to `ui`'s `build.gradle` will do the trick:

```
jar {
   from(project(':shared').sourceSets.main.resources)
}
```